# Is there a way to do query aggregations in Elasticsearch for all products at once?

Tags: python, dataframe, elasticsearch, aggregation

I want to make a pandas dataframe with the daily demand per product. I tried the code below and it gives me exactly what I want for just product_id=1. Is there a simple way to loop this for all products?

```
search_body_statistics = {
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "product_id": "1"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "countPerDay": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "day",
                "size": 10000,
                "order": {
                    "_key": "asc"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
result_stat = es.search(index="sales", body=search_body_statistics)
print(result_stat)

dfProductDay = json_normalize(result_stat['aggregations']['countPerDay']['buckets'])
dfProductDay.rename(columns={'key': 'day'}, inplace=True)
print(dfProductDay)
```

Comment: you can use terms query and pass a list of product ids

Comment: If i pass a list of product ids, it will give me the doc_count of all records that have one of those id's instead of a doc_count per id per day. Am is missing something?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

I think you are looking for [sub aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#run-sub-aggs).

> Bucket aggregations support `bucket` or `metric` sub-aggregations. For example, a `terms` aggregation with an `avg` sub-aggregation calculates an average value for each bucket of documents.

Also, I notice you are using the `terms` aggregation on `day`, maybe you would like to consider using the [histogram aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html) ?

## Solution

I believe the following query would work for you.

```json
search_body_statistics = {
  "size": 0
  "aggs": {
    "PerDay": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "day",
        "size": 10000,
        "order": {
          "_key": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ProductCount": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "product_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```